# Is it possible to learn `Adobe-Indesign CC` quickly?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, layout

I am writing a book. I want to do all stages myself. So, I bought `Adobe-Indesign CC 2014` to design the layout of the pages. I've watched some video online to desgin my layout.
I tried to redesign another book's design. you can see a photo of that book here.
So my questions are:
Is it possible to learn `Adobe-Indesign CC` quickly, considering the fact that I have not enough background in graphic desgin?
What is a good reference to learn `Adobe-Indesign CC`?
Is there anyone interested to help me about this project?
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Speed of learning is *entirely* depended upon the student.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but just Photoshop is not sufficient to create a book. You'll need InDesign in addition to that *at the very least*.

Comment: So, you are saying its not easy :( @Vincent

Comment: argh, I misread. I thought your Q said 'Photoshop' instead of 'InDesign'. Dunno why. Do you know Photoshop and / or Illustrator? If yes, then InDesign shouldn't be too hard to learn.

Comment: No, But I've bought adobe illustrator too. Also watched many video about indesgin, so I know how to layout the page with indesgin. but the problem is I dotn have any background in graphic, so I cannot make something similar to the photo I have posted on here, Also I watched your work , it is impressive!@Vincent

Answer (score 7):

Basically, what you're asking is:

> Is it possible to quickly learn this job you guys've been doing your
>   entire working life?

Short, but blunt: just knowlegde of a certain piece of software is **not** going to be enough to be able to lay-out and create a book.

Yes, Adobe InDesign is can be learned rather quickly if you are a bit savvy with graphic software. I teach a six-hour course in which students get the gist of the program and are able to lay-out and produce a poster or folder. That is just **technical** knowledge, though.

What can **not** be taught or learned quickly is how to create a **good** poster or folder. Or book, for that matter. Lay-out, typography, handling illustrations, composition, colour use, exporting, printing : all are subjects that take experience to do well. A lot of experience.

Your might be a tad bit ambitious when you say 'I want to do all stages myself'.  You're probably not going to be handling the presses that print it, nor drive the trucks that deliver it.

In the same vein, you'd better leave the design to someone who is qualified to do that as a job: a designer.

Comment: I'm sorry if the tone of this answer is a bit caustic, that's not my intention. I'm just trying to reflect that you are asking whether years of experience in a field are 'learned easily'.

Comment: I would compare this with "I bought AutoCAD and watched a few videos. Can I now build a nuclear plant?" :)

Comment: I have downloaded some Vector graphs(Lable,box,...) and edited them with Illustrator and then import them in Indesign. Now I have designed most parts of one page of the book. I am pretty sure that I cannot learn all parts of publishing process, But It think No one know what is in my mind about design of the book, So at least I can try to design it my way and find someone to polish it then. What do you think? Can I post the Jpg of the designed page here so that you can see how it looks and help me with ur constructive comments?  @Vincent

Comment: Please read my comment above @Jongware

Comment: @Jongware well no you dont have to go that far. I mean even 3rd year engineering students would struggle to  even be able to design a hinge for the kitchen door, which is pretty simple tough not trivial.

Comment: I have some sympathy for Electricman I paid  a professional to design some business cards, I gave them the background image and text required. They pick the fonts and layout and sent me PDF preview which I opened and it looked great so I gave the go ahead to print the cards. But one of the fonts came  out very different, turned out font looked okay when I opened the preview defaulting to monitor screen size but if shown actual business card size it did not. The designer should have known that, she would not accept any responsibility.

Comment: I find it is worth taking the time to understand things yourself and have a go at doing it even if it's just to provide a more concrete starting point to pass onto a professional or a way to identify the best professional for the job.